# DISCORD.JS How to get a specific channel ID by name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Fairly newbie question, but my overall goal is to have a dedicated log channel the bot sends messages too. So it would be something like this

`log = logstuff;
channel = [WAY OF GETTING CHANNEL ID BY NAME]
client.channels.get(channel).send(log)`

All inside an async fucntion bc im using Commando.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this means you just have to search the `message.guild` for your `channel`, then send your log;

```js
let targetChannelName = "MY_SAMPLE_CHANNEL_NAME";
let log = "test payload";
try {
  await message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === targetChannelName && channel.type === "text").send(log)
} catch {console.log} // log any errors
```

When you pass a message to this snippet, it searches through the `message.guild`'s channel collection, for a channel with the `name` value of `targetChannelName` and is a textChannel. When it finds the target channel, it sends the `log` content.

Comment: Tiny suggestions: make sure the channel exists first, ensure the channel is a text channel, catch any errors from `TextChannel.send()`, and use camelCase (standard capitalization for variables in JS). Nonetheless this answer will work *(99% of the time)* without them.

Comment: @slothiful I added your suggestions. I just started out writing JS, so I appreciate you helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer will work but you can shorten it down a lot by doing the following:

```
let log = "Your Stuff";
message.guild.channels.find('name', 'channel-name').send(log)
```

Comment: This usage of `Collection.find()` is deprecated and will emit a warning in the console. Stick to predicate functions.